# How to make qr code to personal picture jpg

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, qr-code

**only i need idea how to generate qr code with personal image .**

I need to generate qr code for personal image jpg in windows form c# in visual studio 2015
as this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ou-DFMgh1c

qr code accept string only

How to add image jpg in qr code ?

for generate qr code

```
using (SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|.jpg", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder encoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();
                    encoder.QRCodeScale = 8;
                    string encoding="UserName : " + textBox1.Text + "\r\n" + "CardNo : " + textBox2.Text + "\r\n" + "Address:" + textBox3.Text + "\r\n"+ "Birth Date:"+ dateTimePicker1.Text + "\r\n" + "Personal Image:" + textBox5.Text ;
                    Bitmap bmp = encoder.Encode(encoding);
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                     path = sv.FileName;
                    bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }

            }
```

Comment: can you please any one give only idea and i will solve it

Answer (score -1):

Qr code not have image so that it will encode 64*64 image only

by using based 64 .

convert image to based 64 string is available to encode qr code .

I using this code and it work

```
public string ImageToBase64()
        {
           // path2 = "D:\\pic3.jpg";
            using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path2))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                    base64String = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    return base64String;
                }
            }
        }
```

after that i assign function return to textbox 5

```
textBox5.Text = ImageToBase64();
```